# Unexlained simpleSAMLphp behavior, saying that some SAML responses valid and some invalid

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

IdP is using Ping Federate v6.10. The Service Provider is using simpleSAMLphp.

We have confirmed that the IdP is sending the SAML Assertion to the SP. However it is in the simpleSAMLphp where we get the following error:

```
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] SimpleSAML_Error_Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] Backtrace:
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\www\module.php:180 (N/A)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] Caused by: Exception: Reference validation failed
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] Backtrace:
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 8 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\lib\xmlseclibs.php:1028 (XMLSecurityDSig::validateReference)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 7 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\lib\SAML2\Utils.php:52 (SAML2_Utils::validateElement)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 6 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\lib\SAML2\Assertion.php:469 (SAML2_Assertion::parseSignature)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 5 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\lib\SAML2\Assertion.php:240 (SAML2_Assertion::__construct)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 4 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\lib\SAML2\Response.php:37 (SAML2_Response::__construct)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 3 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\lib\SAML2\Message.php:471 (SAML2_Message::fromXML)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\lib\SAML2\HTTPPost.php:88 (SAML2_HTTPPost::receive)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\modules\saml\www\sp\saml2-acs.php:16 (require)
Jan 07 12:42:37 simplesamlphp ERROR [0ed1b9806f] 0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\simplesamlphp\www\module.php:135 (N/A)
```

The weird thing is that some users work and some do not.  Have you guys seen this type of behavior before?  Is it possible that the cause of this is attributes being pulled from an Active Directory contains weird characters (i.e. objectGUID)?

Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Generally*, this error in simpleSAMLphp indicates an issue with validating the signature, and I would say make sure the proper cers are in place. However, if it's happening only on some users from the same connection, there's got to be something else going on.

You could ask the IdP if they have defined ObjectGUID as a [binary attribute](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/Specifying+LDAP+Binary+Attributes), and [verify the encoding](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF610/Specifying+Encoding+for+Binary+Directory+Attributes) that they are using for that attribute - I suppose it could break something in the validation... That's about the only thing I can think of that might break an otherwise working connection between simpleSAMLphp and PingFederate (disclosure - as it notes in my profile, I do support work for Ping).

If your partner has a valid contract with us, they can always open a support issue if they need help, and we're happy to get on the phone with them (and you) to work through the issue.

Comment: Appreciate the reply.  I believe they have not defined the ObjectGUID as a binary attribute.  If we do change it to a binary attribute and set it to Base64 encoding do you think this would help remedy any encoding issue??

Comment: I think both you and your client have an issue with us on this currently, so you've likely gotten an answer from that... However, I suspect that it is the issue. The objectguid could certainly break the XML. I'm surprised that our mutual client hasn't had this issue previously, if that attribute is in use anywhere else...

Comment: The issue was the ObjectGUID, so if anyone else sees this type of behavior it is due to the fact that encoding of the ObjectGUID sometimes causes the signature to fail.  Our solutions as we used another field sAMAccountName so that we used a string field.  A possible solution to try if you absolutely need to use the ObjectGUID fields is to look at the PingFederate Settings and set the data type to binary and encode with Base64 (again we didn't try this but in theory it should work).  Big thanks to the Ping Identity Support Team, they were solid.